# How to save tcpdump pcap files using -C option

Tags: bash, tcpdump

I am using the following command to capture files.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -C 100 -w test.pcap
```

This rotates files with the names test.pcap,test.pcap1,test.pcap2 ... 
Is there any way to save files with test.pcap,test1.pcap,test2.pcap ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html).  From the `tcpdump` man page:

*Savefiles after the first savefile will have the name specified with the -w flag, with a number after it, starting at 1 and continuing upward.*

If you have [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) available, you can try the following instead:

```
tshark -i eth0 -b filesize:100000 -w test.pcap
```

This will generate capture files of the form `test_nnnnn_YYYYmmddHHMMSS.pcap`

... where:

- `nnnnn` is an incrementing number, beginning with 1 (consistent for all files, unlike `tcpdump`)
- `YYYY` is the year as a decimal number including the century
- `mm` is the month as a decimal number (range 01 to 12)
- `dd` is the day of the month as a decimal number (range 01 to 31)
- `HH` is the hour as a decimal number using a 24-hour clock (range 00 to 23)
- `MM` is the minute as a decimal number (range 00 to 59)
- `SS` is the second as a decimal number (range 00 to 60)

(Notation and description borrowed from [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).)

**NOTE**: `tcpdump`'s *`-C file_size`* option specifies the number of [MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte)'s as the *`file_size`* (i.e., 100 = 100,000,000 bytes), whereas `tshark`'s *`-b filesize:NUM`* option specifies the number of [kB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte)'s as the *`NUM`* (ie., 100000 = 100,000,000 bytes).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think I will use tshark now.